# Creating a Windows 7 Taskbar Icon

Tags: java, windows-7, taskbar, startmenu

### My Goal

---

I want to make it so that, on first run, my program will make its icon appear in the Windows 7 Taskbar. I know that the icon files are shortcuts in `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar` and mostly want to know this:

### My Questions

---

1. How, in Java, can I create a shortcut file (`.lnk`)
2. <s>Is it possible to even access that without admin privileges?</s>

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629393/is-it-possible-to-pin-to-start-menu-using-innosetup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not need admin privileges but you do need to do this in context of the user whose taskbar is being changed.

Here's a library which does what you want: http://alumnus.caltech.edu/~jimmc/jshortcut/

Comment: This is not a .NET application. It is a Java application.

Comment: I thought you might be able to do the transfer, see the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Java library providing the new Windows 7 features for Java. It's called [J7Goodies](http://www.strixcode.com/j7goodies/) by [Strix Code](http://www.strixcode.com). Applications using it can be properly pinned to the Windows 7 taskbar. You can also create your own jump lists, etc.

Comment: I was hoping for something that's free and non-librarian