# Pin folder to the start menu with Inno Setup

Tags: directory, inno-setup, startmenu

Actually I am trying to pin a folder to the start menu of windows 7. With programs I could make that with this inno setup script from TLama I have found on stackoverflow

[Is it possible to 'Pin to start menu' using Inno Setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629393/is-it-possible-to-pin-to-start-menu-using-inno-setup)

But I do not realy understand how to change this script to work with folder. 
Could anyone help me please?

Comment: Windows doesn't offer an option to pin a folder to taskbar/start menu. So that is impossible. Not sure if that works, but you could try to create a shortcut to the folder and pin this shortcut.

Comment: Thanks for your reply TLama. It seems that there is the option to pin a folder and the shortcut of a folder to the startmenu. But unfortunately it looks not like that what I want to get. I have seen from other software that a folder like that in the Windows\Startmenu folder will be shown on the front side of the startmenu and when you click on this folder the folder will be expand and the shortcuts to the executable software will be shown.

Comment: Yes, then pinning is not for you. Pinned apps. reside on the start menu *front page*. You are looking for common start menu shortcuts that you can create from the [`[Icons]`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=iconssection) section in Inno Setup.